# how to display related activities under services using database and php

Tags: php, sql

**PHP code**

```
<?php 

include("connect.php")

$activityid = "select activity.activity_name,activity.activity_id 
               from activity 
               join serviceactivitymap on activity.activity_id = serviceactivitymap.activity_id 
               where serviceactivitymap.service_id = 1";

$activityvalue = $conn->query($activityid) or die ($conn>error.__LINE__);
$activities = [];

while ($row = $activityvalue->fetch_assoc()) {
    $activities[] = $row;
}

$serviceid = "select * from service";
$servicevalue = $conn->query($serviceid) or die ($conn->error.__LINE__);
$services = [];

while ($row = $servicevalue->fetch_assoc()) {
    $services[] = $row;
}
foreach ($services as $service):
?>
 <form action = "index.php   method = "post">
     <input name='serviceone[]' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" type='checkbox' data-id='Incometax' value="<?php echo $service['service_id']?>"/><?php echo $service['service_name']?>
     <br>
     <?php foreach ($activities as $activity):?>
     <input name='activityone[]' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" type='checkbox' data-id='Incometax' value="<?php echo $activity['activity_id']?>"/><?php echo $activity['activity_name']?>
     <br>
     <?php endforeach ?>
     <?php endforeach ?>
 </form>
```

**Output of the code is :**

- Incometax

  - Revised filling
  - Return filling
- Gst

  - Revised filling
  - Return filling
- Tds

  - Revised filling
  - Return filling

I have 3 tables `services`, `activity`, `serviceactivitymap`
where I store `service_id`, `service_name` in services and `activity_id`, `activity_name` in activity and `service_id` and related `activity_id in`serviceactivitymap`but i dont know how to display related activities under services.`
serviceactivitymap` table structure is

- Incometax

  - Revised filling
  - Return filling
- Gst

  - Tax Payment
  - Statutory Audit
- Tds

  - Internal Audit
  - Stock Audit

Can I display it like this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php include("connect.php")?>
<?php 

     $activityid = "select activity.activity_name,activity.activity_id 
                    from activity 
                        join serviceactivitymap  on activity.activity_id = serviceactivitymap.activity_id 
                    where serviceactivitymap.service_id = 1";

     $activityvalue = $conn->query($activityid) or die ($conn>error.__LINE__);

     $activities = [];

    while ($row = $activityvalue->fetch_assoc()) {
        $activities[] = $row;
    }

    $serviceid = "select * from service";

    $servicevalue = $conn->query($serviceid) or die ($conn->error.__LINE__);

    $services = [];

    while ($row = $servicevalue->fetch_assoc()) {
        $services[] = $row;
    }
    foreach ($services as $service):
?>


   <form action = "index.php"   method = "post">

   <input name='serviceone[]' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" type='checkbox' data-id='Incometax' value="<?php echo $service['service_id']?>"/><?php echo $service['service_name']?>
   <br>


<?php foreach ($activities as $activity):?>

   <input name='activityone[]' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" type='checkbox' data-id='Incometax' value="<?php echo $activity['activity_id']?>"/><?php echo $activity['activity_name']?>

   <br>

    <?php endforeach ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
</form>
```

There you go. You are missing a closing quotation mark at form action

Comment: the output is same again

Comment: I dont think you have to add the ":" after the foreach statments

Comment: no sir no any issues when i use curly bracket instead of : then the output remain same